# fatal: could not create work tree dir 'divyanshu': Permission denied

Tags: bitbucket

While I was using Git bash this occurred on my screen while putting the local repository to the remote repository what should I do to resolve this?

I went from private to public to understand if there is any issue regarding the secured line but there was the same output displayed. while I was doing this from https:// not ssh.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in easy ways:

1. Create a repository and Folder in your system with the same name.
2. Open git bash and clone it.
   You will have access to the remote and local repositories.
   Now you can push/pull/delete/check status etc.